# ionic npm dependency errors

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

I am keeping having dependency issues. here:

```
npm install @capacitor-community/http @ionic-native/http @ionic-native/keyboard

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: chatgptApp@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.5.7
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"~7.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/core
npm ERR!   peer @ionic-native/core@"^5.1.0" from @ionic-native/http@5.36.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/http
npm ERR!     @ionic-native/http@"*" from the root project
```

how can such errors be solved?

I have tried the `npm --legacy-per-peer` option but there s dependancy errors then on ionic build

I have tried to update the @ionic-native/core but that give me the same errors `npm install @ionic-native/core@latest`

Same when trying to change rxjs version  `npm install rxjs@^7.5.0`

s

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install rxjs@6.6.7
```

then

```
npm install @capacitor-community/http @ionic-native/http @ionic-native/keyboard
```

not easy though. is there a command to search the next available version that do respond to the peer requirement?